# Невидимые параметры в fiddler или почему мой запрос не проходит?

Tags: c#, http, get

Проблема для меня магическая. Задача - пройти авторизацию на сайте ru.wix.com. Для этого нужно получить определенные куки, отправив определенный запрос. Работаю из приложения на c# с помощью библиотеки xNet. Так вот, проблема в том, что делая запрос из приложения(как через fiddler, так и напрямую), мой запрос не проходит, куки не выдаются и загружаются другие данные. 
Но стоит мне повторить тот же самый запрос(!) из fiddler'а(хот-кей "R" или "Reissue Requests"), как он спокойно проходит, выдаются куки и загружается нужный контент. Этому есть какое-то объяснение?

**UPD**: Заметил, что если повторять запрос с частотой 1сек - то проходит ровно на 5й раз, если с частотой в 2 - то где-то на третий. При этом одиночная пауза в 3-4-5-6сек не подходит, все равно нужно повторять. В браузере и через fiddler проходит все с 1го раза.

**UPD2:**: Попробовал через WebRequest - тоже самое. При этом, если формировать те же самые запросы от начала и до конца с помощью Composer fiddler'a, проходит на ура. Очень прошу помощи.

Comment: Запишите проблемный запрос из приложения тем же fillddler-ом и сравните с оригинальным.

Comment: Не понял это коммента, если честно. Все запросы записаны и идентичны оригинальным. Проблема не в хедерах или Get\Post параметрах, потому что повтор того же самого запроса, но средствами fiddler дает другой результат.

Comment: При запущенном фиддлере все запросы на самом делаются именно фиддлером. Если запросы как-то "не проходят" (не совсем понятно что это вообще означает) - значит что-то глючит или со стороны сайта, или по дороге. Обратиться к администрации сайта не пробовали? Или вы ожидаете что тут кто-то угадает, что именно у вас там в коде "не проходит"?

Comment: Как я и указал в вопросе, "не проходят" - это значит не загружается нужный контент и не выдаются куки при запросе. Принцип работы прокси я понимаю, но я не понимаю, почему, когда я делаю запрос из своего приложения, грузится один контент, а когда повторяю точно такой же запрос средствами fiddler - другой. Причем это не глюк, т.к. срабатывает не стихийно, а стабильно.

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко, вы действительно запишите запрос, который вы проблемным приложением отправляете и сравните с запросом, который отправляете композером фидлера. Наверняка есть различия.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что никаких отличий в хедерах нет. Абсолютно никаких. Скажу даже так, я повторяю тот же запрос, который был отправлен приложением(с помощью хот-кея "R") и он принимается сервером с первого раза. Те же параметры, те же хедеры, все идентично 1:1.

Comment: Может покажите логи/скриншоты и примеры запросов?

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко, не видя ваш код, вам будет сложно помочь. Создайте репозиторий на github.com.

Comment: Возможно троттлинг срабатывает. Не больше n запросов в минуту/секунду. Попробуйте F5 понажимать в браузере (с отключенным кэшем), если повторится, значит вы задолбали сервис :)

Answer (score -1):

Проверь редиректы. .net'овский запрос по умолчанию сам обрабатывает редирект, поэтому если куки были выставлены в ответе, где делается редирект, то ты их пропустил и получил уже следующую страницу (запрошенную без этих кук). Попробуй отключить автоматическую обработку редиректа, достать всё необходимое из ответа и выполнить дальнейшие действия вручную. Кстати, там, где я действовал таким образом, я вообще не запрашивал страницу, на которую сделан редирект - я просто вытаскивал куки и слал следующий нужный мне запрос.

Answer (score -3):

На сколько понял, вы проксируете запрос через фидлер, и он отрабатывает успешно.
В таком случае, скорее всего, библиотека которой вы пользуетесь, не обрабатывает ответ сервера коректно.

Comment: Нет. Топикастер проксирует запрос через фиддлер, запрос "не проходит". Сразу после этого он реплеит его в фиддлере - и запрос проходит. Мистика.